# php resize class failing with larger image file sizes on dreamhost

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image

This is an odd error I'm encountering and reaching out to see if anyone can help me pin down why this is happening.

So basically, I've got a form that uploads an image using jquery ajax, then uses a resizing class http://jarrodoberto.com/articles/2011/09/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php to crop the image. I've noticed with images over 1mb the script fails with no error messages. Also, this is only happening on dreamhost. On my host gatorserver everything works as it should.

What is odd to me is that images smaller in size seem to work fine. All of the php ini settings are well above the limits so I know that's not the issue and both servers are running php 5.6. and have error reporting on.

I've also tested this script directly without ajax and it does not work on images much over 1mb.

```
include('resize-class.php');
$resizeObj = new resize('photo.jpg');
$resizeObj -> resizeImage(250,250,'auto');
$resizeObj -> saveImage('photo-test.jpg', 100);
```

So this obviously is something with the script and how dreamhost is setup.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Upon further testing I'm finding this error
Allowed memory size of 94371840 bytes exhausted
this same test only produces this error on dreamhost and only certain jpg files, not on hostgator. So this has something to do with dreamhost and certain jpg files.

Comment: Does the script fail immediately, or does it crunch for, say, 30 seconds and then just stop without returning a result?

Comment: It fails immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to modify the dreamhost **phprc** file located in /home/username/.php/5.6/phprc to something similar to the following

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 105M
max_execution_time = 500
max_input_time = 250
memory_limit = 256M
```

https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214894037-How-do-I-create-a-phprc-file-via-FTP-

ONE IMPORTANT THING TO NOTE: The changed php settings take about 10 min to take effect as I'm supposing they are part of a cgi process that restarts ever so often.

The memory limit seemed to be causing the error.

Not sure why this resize-class.php script would need that much memory to resize a 1mb photo.

Comment: ImageMagick and GD both take a compressed JPG and turn it into a uncompressed bitmap to process it, so a 1MB file will take up a *lot* more RAM than that.

Comment: Running into resource limits is extremely common on shared hosting. You get what you pay for.